# ASP.NET DropDownList - add get parameter to url after changing item

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, http-get

I have dropdownList in asp.net webforms:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ItemDate"  DataSourceID="dsItems" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Value" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

But url is still this same:

```
http://.../Default.aspx
```

I want to change this method that url should have additional parameter:

```
http://.../Default.aspx?item=23
```

Comment: i dont find any relation between given dropdown and `string item= Request.QueryString["Item"];` how you can get the value of dropdown in querystring like this.. whats the `Item` which u r passing to get in query string

Comment: I corrected this mistake

Comment: hmm right.. now check my answer below this is how you can handle it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the **SelectedIndexChanged** event here bind you DropDown in aspx as follows..

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

then in C# code behind use the following snippet..

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
  Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath+"?item=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but now postback is doing two times

Comment: I'm agree on your point.. javascript there to help you out.. if you are done.. then okay else i will tell you..